# Can't fix CORS error when trying to make requests on AWS Fargate task using NGINX reverse proxy - React frontend to Spring Boot backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, nginx, aws-fargate

the CORS error I received:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:86/item/all. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

The Request Headers:

GET /item/all undefined
Host: localhost:86
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://48.223.257.3/
Origin: http://48.223.257.3
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site

I have an AWS Fargate task running with 4 containers: React frontend, Spring Boot backend, NGINX reverse proxy, and postgres database. It is deployed by a service with a service discovery endpoint of 'example.local'. I created an ec2 instance in the same vpc as the task and inside it sent a curl request to 'http://example.local:86/item/all', which worked. Just fyi, my app worked fine when I tested it locally before trying to deploy it via AWS Fargate (obviously I have made configuration changes since then). Now I have tried both modifying my frontend requests to be to the 'example.local' url (which did not work) and to 'localhost' (which also did not work). Below this I will post a copy of my NGINX config file to show that I should be allowing everything I need.

server {
listen 86;

```
location / {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin' always;
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        return 204;
    }

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin' always;
}
```

}

so since as far as I can tell I have made all of the allowances I need and have sent requests to paths that seemed would be correct, but still got the CORS error, I'm really at a loss for what the issue could be or how to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"the CORS error"_... which appears nowhere in your question

Comment: One possible reason for this error could be that the NGINX reverse proxy is not forwarding the correct headers to the Spring Boot backend. To ensure that the necessary headers are being forwarded, you can try adding the following lines to your NGINX configuration:

proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;

Additionally, you may need to modify the React frontend code to include the withCredentials option when making requests. This will ensure that cookies are included in the CORS request.

Comment: @YusufAdeyemo thank you for the reply. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it produced the same CORS error still.

Comment: I am working on something similar, only I have a express server as my backend. Do I need to make a reverse proxy same as you did?

Comment: My issue was that I needed to have a publicly accessible url for my frontend to send requests to the backend with. So I paid for and registered a domain with Route 53, and set up a hosted zone for the domain with hosted zone record type A with the task's public ip address associated with it. So now my deployed containers' task is associated with the domain I purchased and the url can be used to send requests.